# C# MVC Rote custom configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing

I currently have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { culture = "en-US", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

That makes URLs look like this:

www.site.com/en-US/ContactUs/Index

www.site.com/es/ContactUs/Index

My question is how do I configure routes so that when "culture" is "en-US" URLs will look like this:

www.site.com/ContactUs/Index

But when "culture" is "es" or any other culture (besides en-US) URLs will look like this (example below is with "es" culture):

www.site.com/es/ContactUs/Index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best solution I could come up with by basically hard coding routs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SpanishCulture",
            url: "es/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { culture = "es", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { culture = "es" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultCulture",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { culture = "en-US", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your routes should look as follows:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Culture",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { culture = "en-US", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { culture="en-US", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

The idea is that when you receive an URL with a culture the first route will handle it.

Otherwise, if you receive a route without the culture, the default route will take care of it *"hard coding"* the default culture.

Comment: But with those routes you can still have and MVC will generate ActionLinks with www.site.com/en-US/ContactUs/Index route its only HomeController, Index action will look like www.site.com/ all other URLs will have en-US in them ex; www.site.com/en-US/ContactUs/Index